# Why does MySql throws me error 1242 while I've already added two rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, error-handling, triggers, insert

I'm working on a database, but when I use the statement

> Insert into Personaggio (Nome, Storia, Personalità, StatisticheATK,StatisticheDEF, Salute,Denaro,NomeNEmico, NomeOggetto, NomeArma,NomeChip)
> values ("A2","A2 Ã¨ un androide creato con lo scopo di
> attaccare le linee nemiche delle biomacchine.Tuttavia, essa si ribella
> alla YoHRa dopo alcuni fatti, e vive come una disertrice.
> ","All'inizio Ã¨ taciturna e misteriosa, ma durante la storia si
> scopre essere abbastanza aggressiva e fumantina. Nutre profondo astio
> verso le biomacchine, tuttavia nel corso della storia si ricrederÃ .
> ",1200,500,2000,30000,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

The log console gives me the error 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row. It's clearly not a subquery, so what I am supposed to do? The triggers on the tables are 4, 2 on before insert and 2 on before update and they are basically the same, here's an example:

> CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER
> `NierAutomata`.`Personaggio_BEFORE_INSERT_1` BEFORE INSERT ON
> `Personaggio` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN declare msg VARCHAR(150);
> if (999999 < (select Personaggio.Salute from Personaggio)) then set
> msg=concat('La salute massima non può superare il valore di 999.999');
> signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text=msg; end if; END
>
> I've already inserted 2 records on this table, but only this one is
> giving me trouble. My version is 8.0.23 build 365764. Any help?

I've already inserted 2 records on this table, but only this one is giving me trouble. My version is 8.0.23 build 365764.

Comment: That trigger prevents more that 2 rows in the Personaggio table. Re-write!

Comment: Just use a check constraint instead of a trigger.

Comment: @jarlh how do I tell the trigger to affect only one row then?

Comment: If the `(select Personaggio.Salute from Personaggio)` returns more than 1 row, the trigger will raise an error. I don't know what you're trying to do, so I can't give you the solution.

Comment: @jarlh basically I'm trying to implement a trigger that block the user from putting a value too high in the record Personaggio.Salute. So, the if statement is supposed to check this new value of Personaggio.Salute, but I dont know how to solve it.

Comment: As Shadow already has pointed out, why not use a basic check constraint instead?

Comment: @jarlh beacuse I need at least a few triggers for my project, and that's the only one that I came up with.

Comment: Then no need for select at all, just use NEW.fieldname to access the values to be inserted.